# Finding a name of a file in a list and renaming that file with the index in the list

Tags: python

Newbie in python here, I'm trying to get a list of file names (.wav) from an excel file, find the files with those names under some directory, and rename those wav files by the index in the list.
Here is the simple version my code:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import os

path_before = ""
path_after = ""
path_excel = ""

# the excel file with the names ("Title") of the wav files, I want to save the file name + extension
data = pd.read_excel(path_excel+"data.xlsx")
data['Title_temp'] = data['Title']+'.wav'
filelist = data['Title_temp']

# finding the wav files to be renamed 
file_names_all = glob.glob(path_before+'\*')

# and get rid of the directory to just keep the names
get_name = []
for file in file_names_all:
    temp_name = file.split('\\')
    get_name.append(temp_name[-1])

# for the wav files to be renamed, go through the filelist from the excel file
# and if the name is on filelist, rename it to the index of filelist, 
# so the new name should be a number.wav 
# Also, all the file names are in the list and they all should be renamed, 
# but I couldn't find a better way to do this, so the code below

for filename in get_name:
    if filename in filelist:
        try:
            os.rename(filename, filelist.index(filename))
        except:
            print ('File ' + filename + ' could not be renamed!')
    else: print ('File ' + filename + ' could not be found!')
```

I printed the file names out for both the directory and the excel list, they match (with the .wav extensions and everything), but when I run the code, I always get an error that the filename could not be found. Could somebody tell me what's wrong? (The codes are written in windows jupyter notebook)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your code is working and you need to reduce its size and complexity, here is another version.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

path_before = "path to the files to be renamed"
path_excel = "path to the excel file"
data = pd.read_excel('{}/data.xlsx'.format(path_excel))
files_to_rename = os.listdir(path_before)

for index, file_title in enumerate(data['Title']):
    try:
        # as per your code, the excel file has file names without extension, hence adding .wav extension in formatted string'
        if '{}.wav'.format(file_title) in files_to_rename:
            os.rename(os.path.join(path_before, '{}.wav'.format(file_title)), os.path.join(path_before, '{}.wav'.format(index)))
        else:
            print("File {}.wav not found in {}".format(file_title, path_before))
    except Exception as ex:
        print("Cannot rename file: {}".format(file_title))
```